# Simple Objects Issue

Tags: java, object

These are the instructions for the assignment: In this task, you add four more methods to the APRectangle class and you define a static method that generates a string reporting the defining characteristics of a rectangle.

The first three methods — getTopRight, getBottomLeft, and getBottomRight — together with the accessor method getTopLeft return the APPoint objects that represent the four corners of the rectangle. As you define the three new methods, bear in mind that locations in a Java graphics window are described relative to the window's top left corner. So the further a location is to the right in a graphics window, the greater its x-coordinate. And — unexpectedly — the lower down a location is in a graphics window, the greater its y-coordinate. This means that the bottom corners of a rectangle will have greater y-coordinates than the top corners.

The fourth method, shrink, takes a single argument, the double d, and changes the width and the height of the rectangle to d% of their former values. So, for example, if the shrink method of an APRectangle r is called on the double 62.5, then r's width and height will be changed to 0.625 of their former values.

Finally, the static method printAPRectangle is such that, when its argument is the APRectangle whose top left corner is the APPoint with coordinate (-5.0,3.6), whose width is 7.5, and whose height is 6.3, it returns the string

"[APRectangle (-5.0,3.6) 7.5,6.3]"

As you define this method, pay close attention to the location of spaces. You will probably find it useful to call upon the printAPPoint static method as well as all three of the accessor methods of the APRectangle class.

The code I currently have is:

```
public class APRectangle 
{ 
   private APPoint myTopLeft; 
   private double  myWidth; 
   private double  myHeight; 

   public APRectangle( APPoint topLeft, double width, double height ) 
   { 
     // Code for the body of this constructor is hidden 
   } 

   /* 
    * Code for the accessor methods getTopLeft, getWidth, and getHeight and 
    * the modifier methods setTopLeft, setWidth, and setHeight is hidden 
    */ 

   public String getMyTopLeft()
   {
       return myTopLeft.printAPPoint();
   }

   public double getMyWidth()
   {
       return myWidth;
   }

   public double getMyHeight()
   {
       return myHeight;
   }

   public String getTopRight()
   {
       APPoint myTopRight = new APPoint( myWidth + myTopLeft.getX(), myTopLeft.getY() );
       return myTopRight.printAPPoint();
   }

   public String getBottomLeft()
   {
       APPoint myBottomLeft = new APPoint( myTopLeft.getX(), myTopLeft.getY()- myWidth );
       return myBottomLeft.printAPPoint();
   }

   public String getBottomRight()
   {
       APPoint myBottomRight = new APPoint( myWidth + myTopLeft.getX(), myTopLeft.getY()- myWidth);
       return myBottomRight.printAPPoint();
   }

   public double shrink(double d)
   {
       myWidth *= (d / 100.0);
       myHeight *= (d / 100.0);
   }

   // Definitions of the APPoint class and the static method printAPPoint are hidden
   public String printAPRectangle()
   {
       return "[APRectangle " + getMyTopLeft() + " " + getMyWidth() + "," + getMyHeight() + "]" ;
   }

   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
       APRectangle r = new APRectangle( new APPoint( 25, 50 ), 30, 15 );
       System.out.println( printAPRectangle( r ) );
       System.out.println( "top right: " + printAPPoint( r.getTopRight() ) );
       System.out.println( "bottom left: " + printAPPoint( r.getBottomLeft() ) );
       System.out.println( "bottom right: " + printAPPoint( r.getBottomRight() ) );
       r.shrink( 80 );
       System.out.println( "shrunk to 80%: " + printAPRectangle( r ) );
   }
```

I keep receiving this error:

```
TC1.java:11: error: cannot find symbol 

       return "[APRectangle " + getMyTopLeft() + " " + getMyWidth() + "," + getMyHeight() + "]" ; 

                                ^
```

If someone could please explain what I'm missing it'd be very helpful, Thank you!

Comment: You are passing `printAPRectangel(r)` even though your definition doesn't accept any parameters?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You are creating a new instance of your APRectangle class, however you are not accessing this objects methods. Your main should look like this. Calling the method name on its own without referencing an object will just result in an error about static contexts.

```
public static void main(String [] args){
  APRectangle r = new APRectangle( new APPoint( 25, 50 ), 30, 15 );
  System.out.println( r.printAPRectangle() );
```

2) You are passing parameters to a method that doesn't take any parameters in your main method

```
APRectangle r = new APRectangle( new APPoint( 25, 50 ), 30, 15 );
System.out.println( printAPRectangle( r ) );
```

3) You have an APPoint object called myTopLeft, in your getMyTopLeft method, you are trying to return a String by calling

```
myTopLeft.printAPPoint
```

does this printAPPoint method return a String also? If not your going to get an error.